# search for name and samaccountname at the same time

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

Currently I have a customized people picker in  sharepoint 2010, it searches the search term on the account name, but also on the name.

However its done in 2 different methods. I dont have experience with complex AD queries, but I suppose I can do this in only one and line and with an OR?

What I need is that it matches either, part of the samaccountname OR part of the name

```
public static DataTable ExecuteNameQuery(string rootPath, string search)
    {
        string filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=*" + search + "*))";
        return ExecuteADQuery(rootPath, filter);
    }


        public static DataTable ExecutesAMAccountNameQuery(string sAMAccountName)
        {
            string filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*" + sAMAccountName + "*))";
            return ExecuteADQuery("GC:", filter);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can group and/or operators in LDAP queries using the following syntax, based on your example :

```
string filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(name=*" + search + "*)(samAccountName=*" + search + "*)))";
```

That should perform the search on either name or samAccountName.

Additionnally, MSDN has a [primer on LDAP queries](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa996205%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx).

Hope that helps